# Htc Desire 820 - 'eh' word replaced by 'V'

Tags: text-input

Texting, whatsapp, url of browser, dictionary app or anywhere in the phone, the combination of letters 'eh' when occurred is always replaced with the letter 'V'. 
please help. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'eh' to your keyboard's personal dictionary and it will never happen to you again.☺